# Date format as 06-Apr-2009 04:25 PM

Tags: wpf

How do I format a string to display date and time such as the following?

> 06-Apr-2009 04:25 PM

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WPF now has the `StringFormat` property on the `Binding` class, which you can use as follows:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat={}{0:dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm tt}}"/>
```

Comment: I think it should be <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat='{}{0:dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm tt}'}"/>

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom date format string to get exactly that format:

```
theDate.ToString("dd'-'MMM'-'yyyy HH':'mm tt")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check out the available DateTime formats at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx.

You can also provide custom formats. If you want to display it within WPF when dealing with DateTime's, you can implement a custom [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) and use the converter within your binding to display the datetime's as you want them.